# Oracle select between time and group the count based on each time period

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have a table that contains some information and time example

```
+----+-------------------+
| ID |     DateTime      |
+----+-------------------+
| 1  | 10/1/2014 10:10AM |
| 2  | 10/1/2014 11:00AM |
| 3  | 10/1/2014 12:00AM |
| 4  | 10/1/2014 14:10AM |
| 1  | 10/1/2014 02:30AM |
| 2  | 10/1/2014 10:10AM |
| 1  | 10/1/2014 10:40AM |
+----+-------------------+
```

I want to make a count selection like this

```
from 10:00 to 11:00  ID 1  2 counts    ID 2    1 count
from 11:00 to 12:00  ID 3  1 count
from 14:00 to 15:00  ID 4  1 count
from 02:00 to 03:00  ID 1  1 count
```

So I want to group my search hourly based and count each ID within each hour 
How I can do this in a oracle select statment

Comment: I would research the creation of a "calendar table".  One that contains each hour slot of each day on which you ever need to report.  Then your query is just a case of filtering the calendar table to the rows you want, and then joining on the data.  Not only does this aid performance, but it also makes queries simpler and tidier.  It even makes it easy to get results for the hours that have 0 input records (just using a left join).

Comment: 14:10AM doesn't exactly make sense - first, because you cannot combine AM/PM and 24 hour values, and second, because 14:10 is in the afternoon (should at least be PM).

Answer (score 0):

I'd use three steps for this:

- extract the hour part; you can use `TRUNC(..., 'HH')`
- compute the individual counts using `GROUP BY` with hour and ID
- pivot these results (either using the built-in PIVOT function or with GROUP BY / SUM)

All in all (using GROUP BY and SUM):

```
with v_data as (
  select 1 as id, to_date('2014-01-10 10:10:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as datetime from dual union all
  select 2 as id, to_date('2014-01-10 11:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as datetime from dual union all
  select 3 as id, to_date('2014-01-10 12:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as datetime from dual union all
  select 4 as id, to_date('2014-01-10 14:10:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as datetime from dual union all
  select 1 as id, to_date('2014-01-10 02:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as datetime from dual union all
  select 2 as id, to_date('2014-01-10 10:10:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as datetime from dual union all
  select 1 as id, to_date('2014-01-10 10:40:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') as datetime from dual 
) 
select hour, 
  sum(case when id = 1 then cnt else 0 end) as id1,
  sum(case when id = 2 then cnt else 0 end) as id2,
  sum(case when id = 3 then cnt else 0 end) as id3,
  sum(case when id = 4 then cnt else 0 end) as id4
from (  
  select 
    id, hour, count(*) as cnt 
  from (
    select 
      d.*, 
      trunc(datetime, 'HH') as hour
    from v_data d
  )
  group by id, hour
) 
group by hour
order by hour
```

This works only if the list of IDs is fixed - if you need a dynamic list of IDs, you'll have to resort to Dynamic SQL.